# python script repeats first command after converted to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script which looks like:

```
def main():

    y = input("input number: ")
    x = int (y)
    
    while x>0:
      try:

        driver = uc.Chrome()
        driver.get('url')
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(3)    

        User_Id = driver.find_element(By.ID, "Id")

        User_Id.send_keys(y)

        Next_Button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'id').click()

        time.sleep(3)

        password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

        password.send_keys(y)

        time.sleep(2)

        password_next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
        password_next_button.click()

        driver.quit()
     except:
        driver.quit()   
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and it's working just fine as .py, but when i tried to convert it to executable it keeps repeating the first step (input number: )

Here's the pyinstaller code i use:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "icon.ico" --uac-admin  "path to script.py"
```

so i need to know what causes this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: If that's your whole script, then it's just going to input a number and exit.  You never call the `main` function.  Since the name `uc` would be undefined, this cannot be your whole script.

Comment: yes, this is not my whole script, i said it (looks like) this, i wrote the part that keeps repeating and the part should be running after.

Comment: Then, do you see there is almost nothing we can do to help you?  The code you have shown is does not have a problem.  It will not loop.  We cannot read your mind, and we cannot debug code we haven't seen.

Comment: i'm not asking about a problem in my code, my code is working just fine when it in .py, i'm asking about why the exe repeats the first step only.

Comment: Because there is a problem in your code.

Comment: ok, here's my code.

Answer (score 0):

I asked that question on GitHub and i got the correct answer from a member in Pyinstaller called [rokm (Rok Mandeljc)](https://github.com/rokm).

Here's is [his answer](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6777#issuecomment-1108504996):

"undetected-chromedriver is by [default](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/b2e804e977c9cf3dd9c845474752cac142a72508/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py#L120) using [multiprocessing instead of subprocess](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/b2e804e977c9cf3dd9c845474752cac142a72508/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py#L387-L399).

If you want to use multiprocessing in a frozen application, you need to call [multiprocessing.freeze_support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) at the start of your program (before using any multiprocessing functionality). Otherwise, you end up with endless recursive process spawn, which in your case is held back by the input.

Alternatively, you can try setting use_subprocess to use subprocess module instead of multiprocessing."